# Make first letter of TEXT INPUT uppercase

Tags: javascript, html

Im new to JS but I think the post title does its job. From what i saw by googling this problem, there's lots of ways to solve this issue. But basically, theres a text input field, the user writes 'paris'. how do i make 'paris' turn into '**P**aris'. I need to get the input.value and change it. Obviously, i dont hardcode the sentence, the user chooses the word and i get it as a text input value.

```
let cityName = inputCity.value;
let latestSearch = firstUpperCase(cityName);
   
function firstUpperCase(cityName){ 

    //Assign touppercase() to first letter of string, then add the rest of the sentence by using the actual sentence with the first letter sliced. 
    latestSearch = cityName[0].toUpperCase();

    return latestSearch;
  }
```

Comment: What does `inputString` look like?

Comment: Strings are immutable, `firstLetter.toUpperCase` does nothing at all - even when you would call `upperCase()`

Comment: @Unmitigated i dont really understand your question, inputString is the value of the text input, it changes depending on what the user writes.

Comment: @ValentínSanabria What do you mean by "Make first letter of every city upper case."? Are you trying to split by space?

Comment: @Unmitigated its supposed to be a weather app, and i want the user to input any city he wants to check the weather, i want a history-type of interface where he sees all the cities he searched already, BUT i want it to show for ex "Chicago" instead of "chicago". i thought of turning input into array but dont know how, then found things like split and all that but i dont understand how to use them yet.

Comment: You can simplify this question greatly by explaining your input string structure (if it has any like: 'city1 city2 city3') and what the desired output is. This is confusing - at least for me.

Comment: String manipulation is part of every JS tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your question what I understand truely, you want to uppercase first letter of input string that may or may not contain more than one word. Following this, this code might help

```js
let userData = "lorem ipsum the world"
let newString = userData[0].toUpperCase() + userData.slice(1)
alert(newString)
```

In case you need every first letter of each word uppercase, this might help

```js
let userData = "lorem ipsum the world"
userData = userData.split(" ")
userData.forEach(function(word, index){
    userData[index] = word[0].toUpperCase() + word.slice(1)
})
newString = userData.join(" ")
    alert(newString)
```

Comment: I'm using the string not an array

Comment: Strings are "arrays of characters" (not really, but they act similar)

Answer (score 1):

Splitting a string and uppercasing can be done in the following steps:

1. Split the string by some delimiter -- in this case, we'll assume a space.
2. Iterate over each word and uppercase the first letter while joining the rest of the characters.
3. Combine the string by some delimiter -- we'll assume a space again.

Here is how it could be done:

```js
const titlecaseWords = function(sentence) {
    const splitSentence = sentence.split(' ');
  for (let i = 0; i < splitSentence.length; i++) {
    let word = splitSentence[i];
    word = word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);
    splitSentence[i] = word;
  }
  
  return splitSentence.join(' ');
}

const sentence = 'this is a test';
const sentence1 = 'this is yet another test for the audience';
console.log(titlecaseWords(sentence));
console.log(titlecaseWords(sentence1));
```

Below are links to some JavaScript functions.

[Uppercasing a string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase)

[Isolating a character](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt)

[Splitting a string by a particular pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

[Combining a string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

**Edit**
If you want to use the "functional" functions, here is how it could be done:

```js
const titlecaseWords = function(sentence) {
    return sentence.split(' ')
    .map(word => word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1))
    .join(' ');
}

const sentence = 'this is a test';
const sentence1 = 'this is yet another test for the audience';
console.log(titlecaseWords(sentence));
console.log(titlecaseWords(sentence1));
```

Either one works.  Here is [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) around the `map` function.

Comment: Appreciate the sentiment towards learning, but answers on Stackoverflow need to contain more than just links to offsite tutorials. These are better left as a comment, or, you can improve this answer by [editing it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73128745/edit) and including code examples, especially if they are relevant to the question.

Comment: Understood.  Updating the answer, but these are also links to documentation from MDN -- not some random article to read.

Comment: I understand that, but they are still offsite resources. Answers containing only those are generally subject to downvote/deletion on the grounds that if the code should ever change, or the page gets removed, then the answer is no longer valid. I realize this is unlikely for core documentation, but the rationale still stands 

Comment: No problem! Thanks for being receptive to the feedback and updating your answer; much appreciated 

Comment: You are welcome!  Helps me out as well going forward when responding to other people's questions :rocket